# Minimum Area Rectangle in Swift

Tags: programming-challenge, swift

This is my solution to [LeetCode – Minimum Area Rectangle](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-area-rectangle/) in Swift

> **939. Minimum Area Rectangle**
>
> Given a set of points in the xy-plane, determine the minimum area of a rectangle formed from these points, with sides parallel to the x and y axes.
> If there isn't any rectangle, return 0.
>
> - **Example 1:**
>
> Input: `[[1,1],[1,3],[3,1],[3,3],[2,2]]`
>
> Output: `4`
>
> - **Example 2:**
>
> Input: `[[1,1],[1,3],[3,1],[3,3],[4,1],[4,3]]`
>
> Output: `2`

```
class Solution {
    struct Point_Dng: Hashable{
        var x: Int
        var y: Int
        
        init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        }
        
        var hashValue: Int{
            return x * 100000 + y
        }
        
        
        static func == (_ lhs: Point_Dng, _ rhs: Point_Dng) -> Bool{
            return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func minAreaRect(_ points: [[Int]]) -> Int {
        let points_new = points.map({ (point: [Int]) -> Point_Dng in
            return Point_Dng(point[0], point[1])
        })
        let set = Set(points_new)
        var ans = Int.max
        for point in points{
            
            for point_piece in points{
                
                
                if point[0] != point_piece[0] , point[1] != point_piece[1] , set.contains(Point_Dng(point[0], point_piece[1])) ,set.contains(Point_Dng(point_piece[0], point[1])) {
                    
                    ans = min(ans, abs((point_piece[1] - point[1] ) * (point_piece[0] - point[0])))
                }

            }
        }
        
        if ans == Int.max {
            return 0
        }
        else{
            return ans
        }

    }
}
```

> Note:
>
> 1. `1 <= points.length <= 500`
> 2. `0 <= points[i][0] <= 40000`
> 3. `0 <= points[i][1] <= 40000`
> 4. All points are distinct.

According to LeetCode's note, I improved the hash performance.
I turned

```
var hashValue: Int{
     return "\(x)\(y)".hashValue
}
```

into

```
var hashValue: Int{
     return x * 100000 + y
}
```

because Swift's tuple is not hashable.
The prior one will lead to “Time Limit Exceeded”

How can I improve it further?
In fact I want to know is there something I missed in Swift.
Something out of my knowledge.
Because I did it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Naming

The meaning of some identifier names is hard to grasp:

- What does `Point_Dng` stand for? Why not simply `Point`?
- What is `point_piece` in the inner loop, and how is it different from 
  `piece` from the outer loop?
- `set` is too generic, what does it contain?
- `ans` stands for “answer,” but actually contains the “minimal area” found so far.

#### Simplifications

As of Swift 4.2, the compiler automatically creates the required methods
for `Equatable` and `Hashable` conformance for a `struct` if all its member
are `Equatable`/`Hashable`.

A `struct` also has a default memberwise initializer if you don't define your
own.

The properties of a point are never mutated, so they can be declared as constants  (with `let`).

This makes the `struct Point` as simple as

```
struct Point: Hashable {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}
```

The closure in

```
let points_new = points.map({ (point: [Int]) -> Point_Dng in
    return Point_Dng(point[0], point[1])
})
```

can be simplified because the compiler can infer the argument type and the
return type automatically. Since the array is only needed for creating the
set, the assignments can be combined into one:

```
let pointSet = Set(points.map { point in Point(x: point[0], y: point[1]) })
```

#### Performance improvements

In the nested loop it suffices to consider only those pairs where one point
is the “lower left” and the other the “upper right” corner of a potential
rectangle. That reduces the number of tests, and makes the `abs()` call
redundant.

#### Putting it together

The following version was roughly twice as fast in my tests with 
random arrays of 500 points (on a 3.5 GHz Intel Core i5 iMac, compiled
in Release mode, i.e. with optimizations):

```
class Solution {
    struct Point: Hashable {
        let x: Int
        let y: Int
    }

    func minAreaRect(_ points: [[Int]]) -> Int {
        let pointSet = Set(points.map { point in Point(x: point[0], y: point[1]) })

        var minArea = Int.max
        for lowerLeft in points {
            for upperRight in points {
                if upperRight[0] > lowerLeft[0]
                    && upperRight[1] > lowerLeft[1]
                    && pointSet.contains(Point(x: lowerLeft[0], y: upperRight[1]))
                    && pointSet.contains(Point(x: upperRight[0], y: lowerLeft[1])) {

                    let area = (upperRight[0] - lowerLeft[0]) * (upperRight[1] - lowerLeft[1])
                    minArea = min(minArea, area)
                }
            }
        }

        return minArea == Int.max ? 0 : minArea
    }
}
```

#### Further suggestions

Sorting the point array in increasing order of x-coordinates would allow to
find “lower left/upper right” pairs faster, potentially increasing the 
performance.

Comment: Design: Should `minAreaRect(_:)` be a class/static function? Would a struct `Solution ` be preferable to a class?

Comment: @Carpsen90: Generally yes, but the class and the instance method is *given*  on the LeetCode problem page https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-area-rectangle/ when you submit a solution in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Approach

Here is an alternative implementation that is currently the fastest on LeetCode:

**1-** First, let's create two dictionaries, one all for the abscissae (x-axis) and the other for the ordinates (y-axis) :

```
var xAxisDictionary: [Int:Set<Int>] = [:]
var yAxisDictionary: [Int:Set<Int>] = [:]
```

Each dictionary will store the indices of the elements of `points` that have a certain coordinate. Abscissae are the keys of `xAxisDictionary`. Ordinates are the keys of `yAxisDictionary`.

**2-** `pointsCoordinates` will store unique strings that would represent points, this is faster than creating a struct and relying on the automatic hashing system:

```
var pointsCoordinates: Set<String> = []
```

Using a set rather than an array gives better execution time. In fact, if an array is used, the time limit would be exceeded. As shown by the following graph, `Array.contains` is faster for less than 16 elements. `SortedArray.contains` would be the fastest from approximately 16 up to 256 elements. `Set.contains` is the fastest from 256 up to 500 points :

[image: Contains]

**3-** `indicesToConsider` is a set of indices of points that may be part of a rectangle :

```
var indicesToConsider: Set<Int> = []
```

**4-** Let's fill the dictionaries:

```
for (index, point) in points.enumerated() {
    if var set = xAxisDictionary[point[0]] {
        set.insert(index)
        xAxisDictionary[point[0]] = set
    } else {
        xAxisDictionary[point[0]] = Set([index])
    }

    if var set = yAxisDictionary[point[1]] {
        set.insert(index)
        yAxisDictionary[point[1]] = set
    } else {
        yAxisDictionary[point[1]] = Set([index])
    }
}
```

Notice that optional binding is done using `if var` for `set` to be mutable.

**5-** Then, we only keep points that may be part of a rectangle :

```
for (_, indicesSet) in xAxisDictionary {
    // A vertical side of a rectangle, as described in this problem, has to have two points with the same x coordinate
    if indicesSet.count < 2 {
        continue
    }

    // Likewise, a horizontal side of a rectangle, as described in this problem, has to have two points with the same y coordinate
    for pointIndex in indicesSet {
        if yAxisDictionary[points[pointIndex][1]]!.count > 1 {
            indicesToConsider.insert(pointIndex)
            pointsCoordinates.insert("\(points[pointIndex][0])_\(points[pointIndex][1])")
        }
    }
}
```

Force-unwrapping is safe here, it serves also for brevity.

**6-** Let's traverse the considered indices from smallest to largest :

```
let indicesToConsiderArray = indicesToConsider.sorted()
```

Using a sorted array makes a 500ms difference on LeetCode.

**7-** Initially, we'll consider that the minimum area is as big as possible :

```
var result = Int.max
```

The maximum value of `result` is `40_000 * 40_000` since all the coordinates belong to the interval [0, 40000].

On LeetCode, defining `result` as an integer, initially equal to `Int.max`, was little bit faster than: defining `result` as an optional integer initially equal to `nil`, updating it using `result = min(abs((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)), result ?? Int.max)`, and returning `result ?? 0`.

**8-** Now, traverse the `indicesToConsiderArray`, and calculate the area of the rectangle which is confined between a bottom left corner, and a top right corner :

```
for pointIndex in indicesToConsiderArray {
    let x1 = points[pointIndex][0]
    let y1 = points[pointIndex][1]
    let xPeers = xAxisDictionary[x1]!
    let yPeers = yAxisDictionary[y1]!

    for xPeer in xPeers {
        if xPeer <= pointIndex {
            continue
        }
        let y2 = points[xPeer][1]
        for yPeer in yPeers {
            if yPeer <= pointIndex {
                continue
            }
            let x2 = points[yPeer][0]
            if pointsCoordinates.contains("\(x2)_\(y2)") {
                result = min(abs((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)), result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looping through `xPeers` (or `yPeers`) could also be written this way :

```
for case let xPeer in xPeers where xPeer > pointIndex { ... }
```

Meanwhile, we update `result` if a smaller area is found.

**9-** At the end of our function, if the value of `result` isn't changed, then we'll return `0`, meaning that no rectangle can be formed using `points` :

```
return result < Int.max ? result : 0
```

---

For convenience, here is the whole solution :

```
class Solution {
    func minAreaRect(_ points: [[Int]]) -> Int {
        var xAxisDictionary: [Int:Set<Int>] = [:]
        var yAxisDictionary: [Int:Set<Int>] = [:]
        var pointsCoordinates: Set<String> = []
        var indicesToConsider: Set<Int> = []

        for (index, point) in points.enumerated() {
            if var set = xAxisDictionary[point[0]] {
                set.insert(index)
                xAxisDictionary[point[0]] = set
            } else {
                xAxisDictionary[point[0]] = Set([index])
            }

            if var set = yAxisDictionary[point[1]] {
                set.insert(index)
                yAxisDictionary[point[1]] = set
            } else {
                yAxisDictionary[point[1]] = Set([index])
            }
        }

        for (_, indicesSet) in xAxisDictionary {
            if indicesSet.count < 2 {
                continue
            }

            for pointIndex in indicesSet {
                if yAxisDictionary[points[pointIndex][1]]!.count > 1 {
                    indicesToConsider.insert(pointIndex)
                    pointsCoordinates.insert("\(points[pointIndex][0])_\(points[pointIndex][1])")
                }
            }
        }

        let indicesToConsiderArray = indicesToConsider.sorted()

        var result = Int.max

        for pointIndex in indicesToConsiderArray {
            let x1 = points[pointIndex][0]
            let y1 = points[pointIndex][1]
            let xPeers = xAxisDictionary[x1]!   //Force unwrapping is safe here
            let yPeers = yAxisDictionary[y1]!   //and here

            for xPeer in xPeers {
                if xPeer <= pointIndex {
                    continue
                }
                let y2 = points[xPeer][1]
                for yPeer in yPeers {
                    if yPeer <= pointIndex {
                        continue
                    }
                    let x2 = points[yPeer][0]
                    if pointsCoordinates.contains("\(x2)_\(y2)") {
                        result = min(abs((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)), result)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result < Int.max ? result : 0
    }
}
```

The execution time on LeetCode is `1472 ms` :

[image: 100%]

Compared to `3404 ms` for the accepted answer (which is faster than 0.00%)